# Specifications to build a API context data

Tags: api, api-design, web-api

I was developing a new API, and some doubts appears about context of payload data. Example:

```
{
  "transaction_id": 123,
  "transaction_date": "2022-12-25",
  "user_id": 999,
  "user_some_data: ...
}
```

VS

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "id": 123,
    "date": "2022-12-25"
  },
  "user": {
    "id": 999,
    "some_data: ...
  }
}
```

Grouped the context data is more readable. is there any advantage beyond that? Already exists any specifications about that design? OpenAPI don't talk about it. Has any RFC? Or best practices to model the data context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** It depends. Start with a flat structure. Review it each time when new requirements come. Make structure deeper if it fits new requirements better. Remove depth where it doesn't give advantages any more.

To parse JSON, for application it does not matter, if this JSON is formatted or not. Formatting can just consume resources without any advantage for the application. That's why normally applications send JSON as a single line. Independent on structure such JSON is not good readable:

```
{"transaction":{"id":123,"date":"2022-12-25"},"user":{"id":999,"some_data: ...}}
```

Suppose JSON response has size of 10K, i.e. the line has length of 10 000. Is it really more readable?

You contradict to yourself in your example slightly. Despite you split transaction data into two fields, you have not split it further, into year, month, day:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "id": 123,
    "date": {
      "year": 2022,
      "month": 12,
      "day": 25
  },
  ...
}
```

Why not? Because reading "2022-12-25" is much easier than reading such deeper structure. Also parsing of such JSON in the application could be harder.

Suppose you want to represent an address. If the application client just needs to display the address as a string and does not need filtering or sorting by city or by street name, then a single string may be perfect for this:

```
{
    ...
    "address": "London, 125 South St",
    ...
}
```

You can think of each part of address as of object that has multiple attributes. City has name, square, population etc. Street has name, length, surface type, gradient, etc. House has a number, height, the number of floors, etc. From this point of view you may want to represent an address as follows:

```
{
  ...
  "customer": {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "address": {
      "city": {
        "name": "London",
        "street": {
          "name": "South St",
          "house": {
            "number": 125,
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
        ...
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Depending on use case, this can be helpful or it can be way too complex without any advantages.

And in another case something in between can be better:

```
{
  ...
  "customer_name": "John Smith",
  "customer_address": {
    "city": "London",
    "street": "South St",
    "house": 125
  }
  ...
}
```

Or may be even more simple:

```
{
  ...
  "customer_name": "John Smith",
  "city": "London",
  "street": "South St",
  "house": 125
  ...
}
```

There cannot be right or wrong structure. It depends on the context. This is the reason why there is no specification for modeling of object structures for APIs.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience grouping is always better in terms of API design perspective. First, with grouping you can reuse the same shape across different APIs. Also with object form you can reuse the same shape in different entities that are same types of entities.

Another advantage of grouping is ease of parsing. When you flatten the data then you are offloading grouping/parsing logic to the client. In your case you have implicit syntax such as `<entity>_<property>`. The user should be aware of this syntax to use your API. Which is undesirable because APIs should provide the most utility with the least cost of use (cost is the user's effort to use the API). By grouping, parsing becomes easier because there are json parsers in every language that user can just reuse.